# python-ldap creating a group

Tags: python, ldap

I'm trying to create a security group in AD from a python script with python-ldap.

I'm able to bind my user which has sufficient rights to perform such an operation (confirmed by creating the group from ADExplorer gui client) and search the domain, but when it comes to adding the new group it fails with:

> ldap.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: {'info': '00000005: SecErr: DSID-03152492, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Insufficient access'}

This is the script:

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

server  = 'hidden'
user_dn = 'hidden'
user_pw = 'hidden'

fs_dn = 'ou=fssecuritygroups,ou=tkogroups,ou=tokyo,dc=unit,dc=xyz,dc=intra'


l = ldap.initialize("ldaps://"+server)
l.bind_s(user_dn, user_pw)

groupname = 'mytestfs'

attr = {}
attr['objectClass'] = ['group','top']
attr['groupType'] = '-2147483646'
attr['cn'] = groupname
attr['name'] = groupname
attr['sAMAccountName'] = groupname

ldif = modlist.addModlist(attr)
print(l.add_s(fs_dn,ldif))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error when I try to add a new object under a dn where I am not allowed to add.

E.g. I have access rights to the ldap-server (binding works), I'm allowed to add group-objects under `ou=germany,ou=groups,dc=ACME` - but I'm not allowed to add a group-object under `ou=groups,dc=ACME`.

Maybe you checkout the constraints of the ldap or the like.